# How to Change Color When Tab Clicked

Tags: joomla-3.4, menu, css

Can someone let me know to change the color of a tab when it is clicked. For example, in the attached image you can see that when I click on 'Create a Security Policy Rule' and it shows the background color as Dark Grey. I would like to change the color from Dark Grey to say Light Grey or Red.

Can someone show me how to do that please?

Thanks

Carlton[image: Backgound Image]

Comment: The link to the page is http://www.keylooplabs.com/index.php/workbooks-2/pan-edu-201/module-2-initial-configuration/nsp5-2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a tool like ***Firebug*** or similar for inspect the source code of your page directly in your browser, a tool like this give you information about the CSS selectors and the path to the files.

In this case, it seems that you have enabled the compression of code, add or change this code in your main css file:

```
#je_accord754.je_acc ul ul li:hover > a, 
#je_accord754.je_acc ul ul li.open > a, 
#je_accord754.je_acc ul ul li.active > a {
    background: #F08A36;
}
```

Also here you have an screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Wow. That looks great. I'm going to try it. I will let you know how I get on. Cheers

Comment: Hi, there are over 50 .css files. Can you let me know which css file to edit?

Comment: In your case, try in **menu.css** or **style1.css**

Comment: I tried in menu.css and style1.css and I couldn't see #je_accord754.je_acc ul ul li:hover > a, 
#je_accord754.je_acc ul ul li.open > a, 
#je_accord754.je_acc ul ul li.active > a {
    background: #F08A36;

Comment: Try adding the new code at the bottom of the file, save, clear the caché and reload the page.

Comment: I can't see the code you mentioned anywhere :#je_accord754.je_acc ul ul li:hover > a, 
#je_accord754.je_acc ul ul li.open > a, 
#je_accord754.je_acc ul ul li.active > a {
    background: #F08A36;

Comment: Should I add it to menu.css or style1.css or both?

Comment: Copy the code above and paste it at the bottom of the file, save, clear the caché and reload the page. You can add the code in either of the 2 files.

Comment: Ok. It didn't work by adding it to the bottom of menu.css. Will try adding it too style1.css

Comment: Didn't work by adding to style1.css either :-(

Comment: I just did a cut and paste of your code ..

Comment: See https://www.gavick.com/documentation/joomla/templates/customization/custom-template-css for adding custom CSS to a Gavick Template. Depending on what order the CSS files are loaded, you may need to add `!important` before the closing semicolon in the CSS code.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I check it and this what you have to do, in you joomla go to template and in the files find this template/gk-news2/css/template css

I think you have a folder with this name template css in the left side you have a number find this number 738 in that line you have this code

and you have to change this:

## je_accord754.je_acc > ul > li > a:hover, #je_accord754.je_acc > ul > li.active > a, #je_accord754.je_acc > ul > li.open > a { template css:738

```
color: #f08937 !important;
background: none !important;
```

change this:
color: #f08937 !important;.... for this.... background-color: #f08937 !important;
and delete this: background: none !important;

[image]

---

on your website in that menu click on what you want to change color, then click the right button and select inspect, reviews the code, in your right side is where are the css and there you can change color so you can see which is the one who does that change.

when you have it, look up, there is a league where it indicates the folder, go to your template and searches that folder and there you can change it. Also in that league you can see the number of that code

Comment: ok. sorry for my delayed response. Going to check out your answers now

Comment: It didn't work. I added the following but nothing #je_accord754.je_acc > ul > li > a:hover, #je_accord754.je_acc > ul > li.active > a, #je_accord754.je_acc > ul > li.open > a {
color: #f08937 !important;
background-color: #f08937

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your help but I'm still struggling to change the colour. I managed to change the colour by going to template and adding the code je_accord754.je_acc > ul > li > a:hover, #je_accord754.je_acc > ul > li.active > a, #je_accord754.je_acc > ul > li.open > a { template css:738
color: #f08977 !important;
background-color: #f08977 !important; but I still cant change the colour with my original request which was 'Create a security policy rule' at the link http://www.keylooplabs.com/index.php/workbooks-2/pan-edu-201/module-2-initial-configuration/nsp5-2 ... its driving me crazy!

Comment: I think the problem I'm having is knowing what css to use. Can you help me?

Comment: I have just added an image to show what I get when I right click and then select inspect. I hope you can see

Comment: Just in case you cant see my image, I'm trying to say that when I click on the menu as you did and then right click and select inspect, I don't see href or the css.738 that you see.

Comment: ok, please go the following link and let me know what is the css that you think I should change in order to change the background color  http://www.keylooplabs.com/index.php/workbooks-3/check-point-security-administration/introduction-to-check-point-technology

Comment: HI you have to put this code     color: #FFFFFF !important; 
                                                 background-color: #0088cc !important;             in this line 323 in this file style1 css

Comment: Hi Mara, so I've inserted the following in style1, line 323 and it didn't work: color: #FFFFFF !important; background-color: #0088cc !important;#je_accord754.je_acc ul ul li:hover > a, 
#je_accord754.je_acc ul ul li.open > a, 
#je_accord754.je_acc ul ul li.active > a {
  color: #F08A88;
    background-color: #0088cc;

Comment: I meant to say I added color: #FFFFFF !important; background-color: #0088cc !important; on line 323

Comment: mm it should work. I don't know why it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find where is the file, you have to put you mouse like in the photo, you can see there where is the source

[image]

When I right click and inspect I get the following[image]